# Calling base constructor after InitializeComponent

Tags: inheritance, constructor, derived-class

I'm developing an application which has many panels, all derived from a `BasePanel` user control.
Using the application is very similar for using a wizard - each time a diferent panel is shown above all other panels.
I want to have sort of a timer so when there is no user activity, the first panel is shown.

Here is the base panel code:

```
public partial class BasePanel : UserControl
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public BasePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

        foreach (Control control in Controls)
            control.Click += Control_Click;
    }

    public event EventHandler NoActivity = delegate { };
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NoActivity(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLeave(e);
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

The problem:
The `BasePanel` constructor is called before the derived `InitializeComponent()` is called.
Since `BasePanel` has no controls of its own - no control is registered to the `Control_Click` event.

This is normal inheritance behavior, but still - how can I register the derived class's controls at the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved like this:
I've added this recursive function in the`BasePanel`:

```
public void RegisterControls(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        control.Click += Control_Click;
        RegisterControls(control);
    }
}
```

and in the class which creates those panels:

```
private static T CreatePanel<T>()
{
    T panel = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    BasePanel basePanel = panel as BasePanel;

    if (basePanel != null)
    {
        basePanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        basePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        basePanel.Font = new Font("Arial", 20.25F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
        basePanel.Margin = new Padding(0);

        basePanel.RegisterControls(basePanel);
    }

    return panel;
}
```